# Python Selenium: How to extract outerHTML

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Python Selenium to scrape a webpage and am having difficulty finding the elements of interest. There are a large number of elements of interest on just one page and, ideally, I would like to extract all of them as strings in an array. The HTML code looks like this (the light blue highlighted portion is one of many elements I need to find):

[image]

So far, I have tried statements like these:

[image]

The first one returns an empty object. The second one returns unexpected results:

[image]

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *strings in an array*? You are locating `WebElement` objects, what you see is the `to_string()` representation. Do you want their text? an attribute? something else?

Comment: And you should post html and code as text, not images. Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I am looking for everything highlighted in light blue saved as a string in a single element of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *outerHTML* of link saved as *string*, try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.ng-binding').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

If there are multiple links and you want result for each:

```
[link.get_attribute('outerHTML') for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.ng-binding')]
```

Comment: The second statement provided exactly what I needed. Thanks!